# I want to concatenate the ng-model name with some string during ng-repeat.

Tags: angularjs, html

```
    <div ng-repeat ="x in participantsData">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
   <a data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseThree-{{$index}}" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
            Task Assigned :{{$index +  1}}<span class = "caret"></span>
         </h4>
      </div>
   </a>
   <div id="collapseThree-{{$index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <div class= "form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3" for ="Comments" >Task - {{$index + 1}}: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
               <textarea name="quality"  class="form-control" rows="3" width="100px" disabled = "disabled">{{x.task_description}}</textarea>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3" for ="Comments" >Comments: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
               <textarea name="quality" ng-model="comment{{x.id}}" class="form-control" rows="3" width="100px" ></textarea>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3" for ="Comments" >Total hours spent: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-1">
               <input class="form-control" ng-model="effort" type="number" required>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3" for ="TermsAndConditions" ></label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
               <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkModel" ng-init="checkModel = 'false'"; required="required"> I agree that the above information provided by  me can be released to the customer<span style="color:red"><sup>*</sup></span>                        
            </div>
         </div>
         </label>
         <div class= "form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">
               <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" ng-click = "onSavePartcipantaData(x.id)">Submit</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here, in the code when i am adding different textarea i also want to give them unique ng-model name so that it will be easily distinguished, but while doing that i am facing issues.

Here, i am trying to concatenate {{x.id}} with comment in ng-model, but is is not happening, kindly suggest solutions.

Comment: You will get a parsing error. Try changing `participantsData` array to allow elements have `comment` property. Then access with `{{x.comment}}` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use a concept of `getter/setter` of `angularjs` to achieve your requirement.

- > A getter/setter is a function that returns a representation of the
  >   model when called with zero arguments, and sets the internal state of 
  >   a model when called with an argument. It's sometimes useful to use
  >   this for models that have an internal representation that's different 
  >   from what the model exposes to the view.
- > You use this behavior by adding **ng-model-options="{ getterSetter:
  >
  >   true }"** to an element that has ng-model attached to it.

[**Here is the documentation for the same.**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

So, you have to add `ng-model-options=" {getterSetter: true }"`,

```
 <textarea name="quality" ng-model-options=" {getterSetter: true }" ng-model="getter(x)" class="form-control" rows="3" width="100px" ></textarea>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1 ng-repeat="x in records">
 <textarea name="quality" ng-model-options=" {getterSetter: true }" ng-model="getter(x)" class="form-control" rows="3" width="100px" ></textarea>
{{x}}
</h1>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    { id: 1, comment: "Comment"},
    { id: 2, comment: "Comment"},
    { id: 3, comment: "Comment"},
    { id: 4, comment: "Comment"}
  ]
  
  $scope.getter = function(value){
  return value.comment + value.id;
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rsu9Qu8SmqJoO38iZ39K?p=preview)

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wanted a unique ng-model per each element in the array, e.g. `ng-model="comment1"`, `ng-model="comment2"`, `ng-model="comment3"`. And his attempt was to append an id with `commet{{x.id}}` syntax, which isn't correct.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, thnx for the clarification, I updated my answer and Plunker in the way that OP needed. :-)